# How to set a defined menu size in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set a menu a specific size so that i have not to move the padding in case there is an user who has a tiny name (see the code below)

I tried with multiple display types and floats, i am a newbie to it and we do that in my class lesson sadly we can't use Bootstrap so everything is way harder to center.

Normally it should give this but the user can move (this is the current result of the code below without user name modifications :

[image].

I have some basic php for my later use since i will need to change the users but it's not truely realated to PHP

```php
<?php
include('header.php');
include('body.php');
include('footer.php');
 ?>
```

There i have my header who defines the logo and the first Menu

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/styles.css">
  </head>
<body>
<ul>
 <a href="https://www.suissemobile.ch"><img class="Image-LOGO" src="../pictures/logo_smo.gif" alt=""></a>
 <li><a class="Menu" href="../index.php">Home</a></li>
 <li><a class="Menu" href="news.asp">Excursions</a></li>
 <li><a class="Menu" href="https://www.travel.sbb.ch">Agence CFF</a></li>
 <li><div class="Menu-Login"><a class="Menu-Login-Link" href="www.travel.sbb.ch">Login</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;User : -----</div></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

There i have my body for simply the image

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/styles.css">
  </head>
<img class="Image-Body" src="../pictures/body.jpg" alt="">
<div class="Image-Source">® 2009 - Fondation SuisseMobile - <a href="https://www.suissemobile.ch">www.suissemobile.ch</a></div>
```

And finnaly my second menu on bottom

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/styles.css">
   </head>
<pre></pre>
<ul>
 <li><a class="Menu-Bottom" href="../index.php">Contact</a></li>
 <li><a class="Menu-Bottom" href="news.asp">Degrés de difficulté</a></li>
 <li><a class="Menu-Bottom" href="https://www.travel.sbb.ch">Newsletter</a></li>
 <li><a class="Menu-Bottom" href="https://www.travel.sbb.ch">Impressum</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the most important part is of course the CSS

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    width: 649px;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.Menu, .Menu:link, .Menu:visited {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #2A599C;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-right: 20%;
}

.Menu:hover, .Menu:active {
    background-color: red;
}
.Menu-Bottom, .Menu-Bottom:link, .Menu-Bottom:visited {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #2A599C;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-left: 12.65%;
    padding-right: 12.65%;
}

.Menu-Bottom:hover, .Menu-Bottom:active {
    background-color: red;
}
.Menu-Login, .Menu-Login:link, .Menu-Login:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #2A599C;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.Menu-Login:hover, .Menu-Login:active {
    background-color: red;
}
.Menu-Login-Link {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.Image-LOGO {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 90.7%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
}
.Image-Body {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 40px;
  width: 649px;
}
.Image-Source{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 40px;
  width: 649px;
}
```

I would love to output it in the way that the page is fixed (like now) but if the username moves it doesn't annoys me with the margins. The real problem is mainly would it be possible to set the menu width if yes how? I know `width`don't work as excepted,

Comment: Read about flexbox maybe can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello there I'm not sure if this is what you want it to be like, but you can check http://jsfiddle.net/pt4us5az/1/ 
...
so I just remove `.Menu,` from `.Menu, .Menu:link, .Menu:visited {` and `.Menu-Bottom,` from `.Menu-Bottom, .Menu-Bottom:link, .Menu-Bottom:visited {`

and I remove some css code like

```
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-right: 20%;
```

and

```
    padding-left: 12.65%;
    padding-right: 12.65%;
```

and that's it. hope I help you.

Comment: I forgot, I changed the width in your `ul` to `width: 100%;` and also the code inside `.Menu-Login, .Menu-Login:link, .Menu-Login:visited {`

Comment: Hey actually it's really a good way to do the code a bit cleaner but i would like to have the menus and the body at the same size for the image it isn't hard but for the menu i really can't found out how to do a "fixed" menu size